# I can't get data from JSON to flutter if first, I can't browse the PHP file

Tags: php, json, flutter, browser, verify

I get data from the database using the php and encode to JSON. It works.
Then I use these codes inside flutter. It also works.

But next day my project doesn't work!
If first, I browse relating to PHP file in the browser(Chrome). Then Flutter project works.
But If I can't browse the PHP file, Flutter project doesn't work.
So this PHP file is a project file that users can't know to load first it. :)

I think subject is about the "Verifying that you are not a robot..."
When I load the PHP file first, I see this verification attention. I can verifying the php file. And everything is ok.
But Flutter can't pass this verifying state when calling the PHP file.

I guess problem is about the verifying of PHP file.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is it your PHP file, or someone else's? If it's under your control, remove the captcha. If it isn't, the captcha is intended to prevent this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank @ceejayoz for the answer. 

1) This is my PHP file. 
2) The PHP file is hosted in the same project.
3) One example PHP file is like that: [The PHP Link](https://notaveakor.com/testIT.php)!
4) There is no captcha inside the PHP file. 

Do you have one more idea about fixing it? :)

Comment: Where does the "Verifying that you are not a robot" come from? If I visit your link, I get an error about invalid JSON; there's a `}{` in there missing a comma. Perhaps that's your trouble.

Comment: Hello, @ceejayoz thank you for your care. [This is the main project](https://notaveakor.com/test1/) the project's data (singer, song name, etc) are coming by PHP file. [The PHP Link](https://notaveakor.com/admin/testIT.php). I see one second the letter "Verifying that you are not a robot" when first browsing the PHP file. If I can't browse the PHP file I can't see the data inside the project. The numbers of PHP files are 6. If I browse just one of them I can see all data of the project during the day.

Comment: By the way, I see [the PHP file](https://notaveakor.com/admin/testIT.php) [like that](https://www.notaveakor.com/testITphp.JPG).